# importance of categorical variables in GLM

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, regression-coefficients, importance

How can I decide on the importance of various categories in GLM?
In many cases it is recommended to use the absolute value of the standardized coefficients as a measure of importance. However, this depends on the choice of reference coefficient.

In the example below, depending on the reference level ill determine that the $x=4$ category is the most important or $x=1$.

The problem exacerbates when inspecting multiple factors and trying to figure which factor is more important. Is there any method to handle the issue? A way to assign importance to categories that is invariant to the selection of the reference level?

Example:

```
> n <- 30000 
> x <- sample(1:4, n, replace=TRUE)
> 
> df <- data.frame('x' = as.factor(x), 'z' = as.factor(z))
> 
> y <- -10 * (x == 1) - 5 * (x == 2) + 5 * (x == 3) + 10 * (x == 4) + rnorm(n)
> tmp_lm <- lm(y ~ relevel(df$x, ref='2'))
> summary(tmp_lm)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ relevel(df$x, ref = "2"))

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.1705 -0.6756  0.0035  0.6695  3.9079 

Coefficients:
                          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)               -4.99803    0.01159  -431.3   <2e-16 ***
relevel(df$x, ref = "2")1 -4.99321    0.01629  -306.5   <2e-16 ***
relevel(df$x, ref = "2")3  9.98696    0.01635   611.0   <2e-16 ***
relevel(df$x, ref = "2")4 14.98680    0.01636   916.0   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9983 on 29996 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9843,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9843 
F-statistic: 6.277e+05 on 3 and 29996 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

> 
> tmp_lm <- lm(y ~ relevel(df$x, ref='3'))
> summary(tmp_lm)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ relevel(df$x, ref = "3"))

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.1705 -0.6756  0.0035  0.6695  3.9079 

Coefficients:
                           Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                 4.98893    0.01153   432.8   <2e-16 ***
relevel(df$x, ref = "3")1 -14.98018    0.01625  -922.1   <2e-16 ***
relevel(df$x, ref = "3")2  -9.98696    0.01635  -611.0   <2e-16 ***
relevel(df$x, ref = "3")4   4.99984    0.01632   306.4   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9983 on 29996 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9843,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9843 
F-statistic: 6.277e+05 on 3 and 29996 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: For any number of categorical factors in a linear model, all that's being done is reporting on the (conditional, if there are covariates) means' locations relative to one another. In fact, in the examples posted above its easy to see how all the levels are linear transformations of one another and that the fit to the data is identical. The mean of group 4 is highest and the mean of group 1 is lowest; the coefficients values shift relative to the mean reflected in the intercept.  What are you trying to show in the analysis? That might be a helpful place to start.